# Running UI tests on Bamboo

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, ui-testing

Good time of day everyone!
We faced a problem running UI tests on bamboo.
The problem is that they are failing looks like due to that bamboo somehow suppresses windows of UI tests(or hides(most likely)) them. Running the same tests on the same machine with the same user ends up fine.
So the question is how to set up bamboo to run UI tests properly not hiding windows?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What UI testing tool do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason.
On windows starting from Windows 7 all services run in isolated sessions(session 0) which does not allow to communicate with the Desktop.
So the solution was to run bamboo agent from command line not as a service.